# Quickest way to create a top to bottom un-ordered list instead of left to right

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to create a navigation menu that goes from top to bottom. Currently I have a 300px wide `<ul>` with 150px `<li>` inside it. See layout below...

[image]

Currently my list floats left to right (naturally) but I'm struggling to figure out how perhaps I can get it to appear like its going from top to bottom. so the numbers appear in order vertically.

Ideally I don't want to use jquery to do this, but if this is the simplest way then so be it. I would rather some PHP output it in a custom order.

I am using wordpress's get_post to get calendar results.

```
$events = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'motogp-2014',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'event_calendar_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));

if ($events) {

    echo '<ul id="circuit-navigation">';  

    foreach ($events as $event) {
```

Is the some way of ordering the query by a custom order?

See below the order that I need the posts to be in... These are the post ids.

The only problem is I can't get the posts in this order as wordpress does not have an custom order function by id. If I orderby - the it orders the id's numerically. I need them in the order that the id's appear below.

```
array(1045,1093,1047,1097,1053,1100,1059,1105,1063,1112,1073,1118,1075,1121,1085,1123,1087,1130,1089)
```

If any one has a suggestions to help me that would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achive something like this is doing it with the columns feature for css.

```
#circuit-navigation {
  columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
}
```

**Here is a working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/LxnFZ/

```
                            ******BE AWARE******
```

This is just for newer browsers. To see a list for compatibility check out [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=columns)

Comment: Oooo I like this - I can live with the current support

Comment: Is there anyway to remove the gutter? http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/LxnFZ/3/

Comment: Don't worry dude, found answer here: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/

Comment: Nice. Sorry wasn't online for 9 hours.